# How to extract email id from rss feed with yahoo pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I am using a rss feed from Craigslist using yahoo pipes which is working fine. After getting the feed i just want to extract email id from the feed . Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I Link to your pipe would have been useful. Anyways, using rename module create a copy of whatever node that contains the email address to a node say "email". Now use a regex module to  effect
In items.email replace ^.*\s([a-zA-Z0-9._]*?@[a-zA-Z0-9._]*?)\s.*$ with $1
this should work fine